# How to find detached SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I detached a SQL Server database named `company_content` as I thought it was no longer needed but didn't want to delete it just yet.

Turns out I need it. When I tried to attach, I couldn't find `company_content` in the list. Apparently the database name doesn't match up with the `.mdf` name.

How can I find it?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Check the other MDF files where you would otherwise expect the database files to be stored, as it could have been saved under another name.  If that doesn't turn up anything, you can try doing a search for any files on your system with an .MDF extension; perhaps it was simply saved somewhere a little out of the way (in which case, this would be a great opportunity to move it somewhere more reasonable).